# Find a variable and replace it with a variable using str_replace WP

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

I'm trying to use str_replace in my custom plugin to find a variable, replace with and different variable, and search for it in the html5 header tag... like this

```
if ( is_page( "Event Photo Uploader" )) {

    $revised_subtitle = 'Event Photo Uploader';

    $new_subtitle = str_replace( $subtitle, $revised_subtitle, "<header" );
    return $new_subtitle;

}
```

This is failling to work for me and I don't know why. I'm still a bit new to this more advanced stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need `str_replace()` here. Just do `return 'Event Photo Uploader';`?

Comment: Is this the full code? Where does $subtitle come from?

Comment: You str_replace function searches whatever the value of $subtitle is in the string "<header". I doubt that's what you're going for.

Comment: @AmalMurali, I'm not understanding what you're saying... where should I use    return ?

Comment: @Designer17: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but if you're just trying to replace the subtitle for a particular page, then you could remove everything in the function and just `return` the subtitle, as I said in my previous comment.

Comment: @Gavin, This is a custom plugin for a prebuilt them which uses $subtitle in place of WP's tagline.

Comment: @AmalMurali, the function is coded into the theme I'm doing this in a plugin. So I'm trying to change the subtitle to say "Event Photo Uploader" instead of the subtitle.

Comment: @TsanyoTsanev, I know the value of $subtitle and yes I want to search and replace everything within it... what I'm not sure of is if I can use html tags to search in?

Comment: @Designer17: What do you mean `use HTML tags to search in`?

Comment: @AmalMurali: the third element in 'code'str_replace'code' is the string or variable which it searches for the first element... [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp) I'm wondering if it's not working because it doesn't view what I have as valid or what?

Comment: well if you want to search IN it it would be the 3rd parameter of the function, not the first. It goes str_replace($text_to_remove, $text_to_insert, $the_String_you_are_replacing_in)